How to make UEFI shell reading contents of the ISO or DVD?
I have been looking for way to create an ISO file that contains tools that I use often. The ISO file can be mounted remotely through BMC, and lauch the tool through UEFI shell. So far, the UEFI shell can only see the bootx64.efi of the EFI/BOOT/ directory. How do I make the bootx64.efi see my 4.4GB "tools.img" file that contains my tool?
My file structure is like following boot/grub/x86_64-efi/*.mod (All the grub modules I copied from /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/)
├── EFI │   └── BOOT │   ├── bootx64.efi │   ├── efiboot.img │   ├── grub.cfg │   └── grub-stub.cfg └── isolinux └── isolinux.bin
cat grub-stub.cfg
insmod all_video insmod efi_gop insmod efi_uga insmod video_bochs insmod video_cirrus
insmod iso9660 insmod udf insmod fat insmod efifwsetup insmod efinet
search --no-floppy --label TOOLS --set root set prefix=($root)/boot/grub configfile /grub.cfg
I would appreciate if someone can give me some hints or advice on how the grub.cfg should be look like.
Thanks
